# How to check if value in array is true

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using vba and I get str as string
I want to acomplish following task.

there are following array;

```
array1 = (string1, string2, string4)
array2 = (string3, string6, string7)
array3 = (string3, string6, string7)

str = some string

if str is present in array2 then
 sbj = "subject2"

if str is present in array1 then
sbj = subject1
```

like wise
I kno I am confusing but currently I am stuck with long switch funciton (which works well)

```
Function sw(s)
    sw = Switch(s = "a", "Apple", s = "b", "Banana", s = "c", "Apple", s="d", "banana")
End Function
```

means a and c both are apple and b and d are banana like that. Can we use something else for this?

Comment: Create simply function called e.g. ```IsPresent(str, arr)``` and in this function loop through the arr and compare str against each item. When match then exit loop and return ```true```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

join the array and check that way

```
Dim test As Boolean
Dim findStr As String
Dim result As String

findStr = "apple"

varArray = Array("banana", "apple", "pear", "orange")

test = Join$(varArray, " ") Like "*apple*"

result = "apple is " & IIf(test, vbNullString, "not ") & "included"
```

saves having to loop through the array.

---

Even better, is to re-think your approach. Arrays are there to store sets of similar data in a very basic way but you need something a bit more useful so look at using a [`Collection`](http://excelmacromastery.com/Blog/index.php/the-complete-guide-to-collections-in-excel-vba/), [`Dictionary`](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) or [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) object instead.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Let me check.

Comment: The problem is that you can have pinneaple in the array and the test will return true, but apple is not in the array.

Comment: @Clon vague answer to a vague question - there are ways of making it more accurate (using the delimiter in the match pattern for example) but the real point I wanted to make here is that the generic `Array` class is probably the least suitable object for this kind of problem.

Comment: @MacroMan: I also hate the way I am doing thing. My actuall problem is much more complex and therefor I think I should Use json for that. https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject :  If you use a Scripting.Dictionary object as Macro Man suggests, it has a Exists(key) built-in function that checks whether an element with the key is present in the dictionary. You need to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" if you want to use early bound variables.

Comment: Thanks. I like vbajson. They also have example to open .json file and parse.

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject: Yes, if you are dealing with json files, then VBA-JSON is a great library to add to your project.

Comment: I don't know where I am making mistake but, vba-json is not working for me. I will have to see how to make it work.

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject Judging from [your other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36868759/692942) you are not adding the reference in VBA to the Scripting Runtime as directed on the[VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) github page.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a private function to check wether an element is in an array or not, and use this function in your IF .. THEN clauses.

```
Public Function elemInArray(ByVal elem As Variant, ByVal Arr As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim el As Variant

    elemInArray = False

    Select Case IsObject(elem)
    Case True
        For Each el In Arr
            If el Is elem Then elemInArray = True: Exit Function
        Next el

    Case False
        For Each el In Arr
            If el = elem Then elemInArray = True: Exit Function
        Next el

    End Select

End Function
```

EDIT: Or this, simpler function, if your array contains only primitive types

```
Public Function elemInArray(ByVal elem As Variant, ByVal Arr As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim el As Variant

    elemInArray = False

    For Each el In Arr
        If el = elem Then elemInArray = True: Exit Function
    Next el

End Function
```

Then you can ask things like this:

```
if elemInArray(str, arr1) then 
    sbj = "subject1"
```

As for your second question, you can also use IF conditionals or a SELECT CASE statement, like this:

```
IF s = "a" or s = "c" then
    sw = "Apple"
ELSEIF s = "b" or s = "d" then
    sw = "banana"
ELSE
    err.raise 10000,"Unexpected value"
ENDIF
```

or

```
SELECT CASE sw
CASE "a","c"
    sw = "Apple"
CASE "b","d"
    sw = "Banana"
CASE else
    err.raise 10000,"Unexpected value"
END SELECT
```

You can omit the ELSE part if you can guarantee that s will be one of "a", "b", "c" or "d".

Regards

Comment: Thanks for answer. Let me check

Comment: You don't really need the SELECT CASE in the elemInArray function. You can just keep the ( FOR EACH el IN Arr    ...   If el = elem Then .... Next el     )  part. The rest is just in case you want to use the function with an array of objects.